# Is there a better way to thread this class function?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have a class `bar` that keeps track of `N` instances of class `foo` in a `std::map` (so `N` = `map.size()`).
When I call `bar::func` I want to have `N` threads that call `foo::foo_func`.

`foo::foo_func` requires multiple arguments though, namely the instance of `bar` that it's related to.

I was thinking of doing *something* like:

```
void * _threaded_foo_func(void *);

struct box {
  bar * the_bar;
  foo * the_foo;
};

class bar {
  class sub_bar {
    // stuff
  };

  map<foo*, sub_bar*> foo_mappings;

  void func() {
    pthread_t threads[ foo_mappings.size() ];
    map<foo*, sub_bar*>::iterator it = foo_mappings.begin();
    int i=0;
    for(it; it != foo_mappings.end() && i < foo_mappings.size(); ++it, ++i) {
      box * args = new args();
      args->the_bar = this;
      args->the_foo = it->first;
      pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, _threaded_foo_func, (void*) args);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<bar_mappings.size(); ++i) {
      pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

  }

};

void * _threaded_foo_func(void * args) {
  box * b = (box*) args;
  bar * the_bar = b->the_bar;
  foo * the_foo = b->the_foo;
  the_foo->foo_func(the_bar);
  return NULL;
}
```

My questions are:

- Is there a better way to do this? Cleaner? Thoughts on using
  `fork()`?
- Does this look like a poor design of the relationship
  between foo & bar?

**To make this fun, you're only allowed to use pthread.h, no C++11 stuff :)**

Comment: Can you use C++11's `std::thread`?

Comment: If your threads are cpu bound, starting one for every element in the map will overload the CPU.  A better technique is to create a pipe/mailbox with the number of worker threads for the number of cores on the machine and then feeding the arguments into the pipe.  Each thread is a loop reading from the pipe and then exits when the pipe is empty.

Comment: I'd like to, but let's say that we're a special kind of lazy and would just rather use pthread.h

Comment: @K-RAN: Then look into (for one example) Anthony Williams's implementation of a [thread-safe queue using condition variables](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html).

Comment: @BurtonSamograd -- How do I ensure that the threads are not CPU bound, if possible? Also, say that I were to implement the pipe/mailbox schema with worker threads: is there a way to find out the number of cores that the native machine has? I'm kinda new to this particular side of C/C++ programming so any kind of reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your threads are not doing IO then they are probably CPU bound.  Finding the number of cores is not portable so it's difficult to say how you would do that unless we knew your operating system.  One linux you can just grep /proc/cpuinfo, but on windows, I'm really not sure.

Comment: Say that I fire off a set number of threads, say `M` of them, and as each one joins it is immediately assigned a new task; do this until we've processed all `N` `foo` objects. Assuming that the entire program cannot procede without all `N` `foo` objects processed, how is it different from utilizing a thread pool?

Comment: Also, no one has answered my second question.

Comment: Firing off N processing threads vs. N tasks being serviced by M threads (where M is based on the number of available cores) will be less efficient because of extra task switching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many instances of `foo` are you going to have?  Spawning a large number of threads or forking a large number of processes isn't going to scale well in terms of both CPU and memory resources.

Another approach that generally has better scalability is a [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern).  The basic idea is that you have a fixed number of threads that pull and execute tasks from a queue, resulting in better resource utilization.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at C++'s new [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) class, which is part of the C++11 standard library. Its constructor is scheduled to run the created thread immediately and takes a function object such as a function pointer or [lambda function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions) and function arguments. It has the same mechanisms and functionality as pthreads but is platform-independent and object-oriented, making your code cleaner and more consistent with C++ style.

std::thread can be used in gcc by compiling with the `-std=c++0x` flag for gcc 4.6 and earlier (I believe back to 4.4) and with `std=c++11` on gcc 4.7. Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support it, and it can be used in Visual Studio 11 by default.

Comment: I didn't specify in the question that you're only allowed to use pthread.h, sorry about the confusion. I'll definitely take a look at C++11 though so thanks!